# something.appendChild is not a function error

Tags: variables, appendchild, createelement

Hi? I'm trying to build a note app by myself for the first time.
I used createElement and appendChild to make a note in my noteContainer.
and I got an error, "app.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: noteContainer.appendChild is not a function
at HTMLButtonElement.addNewNote"
I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
    const btn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
    const noteContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("note-container");

    const addNewNote = () => {
        const newObj = {
            id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
            content: ""
        };

        const note = document.createElement("p");
        note.innerHTML = newObj.content;

        noteContainer.appendChild(note);
    
    };

    btn.addEventListener("click", addNewNote);
```

I tried to change noteContainer to document.body in addNewNote function, to find the problem.
and it worked fine in that case. which could mean my noteContainer variable is the problem??
but I don't see any problem with it...